# mysql: avg vs sum/count

Tags: mysql, count, sum, average

I have 4  variables:

- amdt_adopt
- com_amdt_adopt
- amdt_tabled
- com_amdt_tabled

I want to compute the average of the ratio:

```
(amdt_adopt - com_amdt_adopt) / (amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled)
```

If I use the built-in `avg` function:

```
select avg((amdt_adopt - com_amdt_adopt) / (amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled)) as final_res
from europolix.act_act
where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0;
```

I get `0.44771942`.

If I use a `sum` and then divides by `count`:

```
select 
(
    select sum((amdt_adopt - com_amdt_adopt) / (amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled))
    from europolix.act_act
    where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0
) 
/ 
(
    select count(*) 
    from europolix.act_act
    where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0
) as final_res;
```

I get `0.20883803`.

I have different results but these two queries are supposed to be equivalent! What's wrong?

### EDIT

Cast to `decimal` as suggested:

```
select avg((cast(amdt_adopt - com_amdt_adopt as decimal(8,3)))  / (cast(amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled as decimal(8,3)))) as final_res
from europolix.act_act
where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0;

select 
(
    select sum((cast(amdt_adopt - com_amdt_adopt as decimal(8,3))) / (cast(amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled as decimal(8,3))))
    from europolix.act_act
    where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0
) 
/ 
(
    select count(*) 
    from europolix.act_act
    where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0
) as final_res;
```

Still same result :(.

Comment: What data types do the columns have?

Comment: They are `integers`. Should I cast them to `float`?

Comment: Yes, cast it to `decimal` for instance

Comment: I just tried, same result (see edit).

Comment: Are there rows in which `amdt_tabled` equals `com_amdt_tabled`?

Comment: Yes! And that's the problem... How to make the `avg` function count those cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have NULL values in records for some of those columns that you use in avg, the results of avg or sum/count might easily differ.

E.g.:

```
create table t (id int, x int, y int);

insert into t (id, x, y) values (1, 1, 1);
insert into t (id, x, y) values (2, 2, 3);
insert into t (id, x, y) values (3, 3, 4);
insert into t (id, x, y) values (4, NULL, NULL);


select avg(x), sum(x), count(x), count(*), sum(x)/count(*) from t;
```

Will give you:

```
AVG(X)  SUM(X)  COUNT(X)    COUNT(*)    SUM(X)/COUNT(*)
2       6       3           4           1.5
```

Similarly, AVG won't consider where a *division by zero* occurs.

E.g.

```
select avg(x/(y-x)) from t where x>0 and y>0;
2.5

select sum(x/(y-x))/count(*) from t where x>0 and y>0;
1.66666667
```

One solution might be to use avg with a condition like this:

```
select avg(if(y-x=0, 0, x/(y-x))) from t where x>0 and y>0;
1.66666667
```

An example can be seen [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68e7f/3)

[edit] updated to consider the possibility of division by zero

Comment: Good idea but that's not the problem here, since I use the condition `where var>0`. Jack just found the problem: when the denominator is equal to 0, the `avg` does not take into account the instance! How to make `avg` take into account those instances?

Comment: you are correct, I should have notice that. you can use maybe something like `avg(if(amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled=0, 0, (amdt_adopt - com_amdt_adopt) / (amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled)))`

Answer (score 2):

As explained by `Jack`, when `(amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled)=0`, the `avg` function doesn't take the instance into account, but the `count` function takes it into account. So the results are different.

If you don't want to take these instances into account and use the `sum` and `count` functions, add a condition in the `count`:

```
select 
(
    select sum((amdt_adopt - com_amdt_adopt) / (amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled))
    from europolix.act_act
    where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0 
) 
/ 
(
    select count(*)
    from europolix.act_act
    where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0 and (amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled)<>0
) as final_res;
```

If you want to take these instances into account (as 0) and use the `avg` function, add an `if` condition as suggested by `lp_`:

```
select avg(if(amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled=0, 0, (amdt_adopt - com_amdt_adopt) / (amdt_tabled - com_amdt_tabled))) as final_res
from europolix.act_act
where validated=2 and com_amdt_adopt>0 and amdt_adopt>0 and com_amdt_tabled>0 and amdt_tabled>0;
```

**Solved!**

Comment: Glad you've figured this out by yourself :) you could change the condition to `IF(amdt_tabled = com_amdt_tabled, 0, ...)`

Comment: Even shorter! Thanks ;).